# Two ::after pseudo-elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'd like to apply two css `::after` pseudo-elements to a single DOM element, each with a different colour. (Yes, I could wrap the DOM element in another DOM element and give each one and `::after` pseudo-element, but my preference is cleaner html.)

I doubt it's possible, but wonder if someone can tell me better.

I especially doubt the possibility of chaining `::after` pseudo-elements together so that one `::after` pertains to another, which pertains to a DOM element, but if anyone knows how to make that happen, please do tell.

Comment: Are you already using `::before`?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't find that duplicate when I searched for the question. I've voted to close (but can't delete now because someone got upvoted).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use a `:before` pseudo-element in addition to your `:after` - http://jsfiddle.net/BePSq/

Comment: In the future, this may become achievable through using [:after(2)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#inserting0)

Comment: @Safareli Nothing in the linked spec document supports that.

Answer (score 11):

You can't add two `::after` pseudo-elements to one DOM element. You can however add an `::before` additionally. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, this may work.

Comment: How can you add two ::after pseudo-elements to one DOM element? Any example?

Answer (score 3):

You can use both the :before and :after pseudo-elements simultaneously on one DOM element. Just make sure you position them correctly. I believe :before places the psudo-element before the parent one, while :after places it after in the html. You can only use these two however and cannot add more pseudo-elements than that.

Comment: They're effectively both child elements of the parent element, with `::before` appearing before the element content, and `::after` coming last.