# How to have pseudo-elements on pseudo-elements?

Tags: css

This creates two pseudo elements:

```
.myElement {}
.myElement::before,
.myElement::after {
    content: '';
}
```

How to add more pseudo elements to the element? Is there a way to add a pseudo element to another pseudo  element?

Comment: I am surprised no one has asked this before. I might be using wrong keywords to find the existing questions.

Comment: [Similar question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007546/adding-pseudo-elements-after-pseudo-elements)

Comment: Nope. There is just `::before` and `::after`. Also, you didn't search very hard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855890/two-after-pseudo-elements and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007546/adding-pseudo-elements-after-pseudo-elements

Comment: The phrasing of other question is just bizarre.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

The pseudo elements are defined as (by [**W3 docs**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content))

> **12.1 The :before and :after pseudo-elements**
> As their names indicate, the :before and :after pseudo-elements specify the location of content before and after an element's document tree content.

Since the *document tree* is the element's defined source code, a pseudo element cannot contain another pseudo element, since it has no tree.

Answer (score 2):

There is a CSS pseudo element '::before(2)' but unfortunately, there isn't any browser support yet for this :

```
div { content: 'A' }
div::before { content: 'B'; }
div::before(2) { content: 'C'; }
```

...would result in the following rendering objects:

```
,-----------------------.
| ,---. ,---.           |
| | C | | B | A         |
| `---' `---'           |
`-----------------------'
```

Source : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#inserting0

Browser support : http://realworldvalidator.com/css/pseudoelements/::before%282%29

Comment: It doesn't do what you seem to think it does. Here is a simple example, http://jsfiddle.net/29zxmfbv/1/.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas Ok, i don't undestand you need 2 `content` properties. Updated my answer, but it can't help you for now.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for doing the research. Got my up vote. : )

Comment: Why was it downvoted? oO Reference to an obscure but existing part of a W3C draft, visual explanation and note on no support: +1

Comment: @GajusKuizinas Thanks, can you put your question as "answered" by clicking on the tick of the answer that help you the most.

Comment: The answer should be chosen when it actually solves the problem. I will choose this as an answer as soon as `::before(n)` is supported by either of the major browser vendors.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, you may need to wrap your element in another.